# vscode source control connected to remote host, is showing clock icon

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Suddenly today, when I connected to the same remote host through `ssh`, `vscode` starts showing clock sign. Despite local changes, `git source control` is not showing any changes

1. Initially `index.lock` file existed, and I deleted that, but did not help
2. I made sure `git` is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vscode seems to do `git status -z -u` (git default `-uall`) in the repository. It turns out I had added a lot of untracked files in the repository unintentionally, and the git command was taking a lot of time. So, I removed many of these unintended files, and this issue went away.